# Is there a 'simnet mode' for Ethereum?

Tags: testnets, unittesting

[simnet](https://gist.github.com/davecgh/2992ed85d41307e794f6) is a feature of the Bitcoin client btcd, which allows a user to create a virtual test network where he can create blocks at ease.

Is there a similar feature for Ethereum/geth? What's the easiest way to test/try out a smart contract on a private test network?